# SQL Server Management Studio 2012 reset Help to Online

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms-2012

I installed SQL Server Management Studio 2012 yesterday and when started Help by pressing Shift F1, I accidently selected Local Help only. Now I don't have help files installed in my system. So if I select any keyword and press Shift F1 - the Help Viewer opens up saying: **Can’t find requested content on your computer.**

I click on Help Library Manager - it opens up a dialog box saying "Set Local Content Location". I don't have any option to reset it back - so that it searches for the help from online.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation I found that it looks like the setting is stored in the file
`%AppData%\Local\Microsoft\HelpLibrary\HelpClient.cfg`

Change this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="helpmode" value="offline" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="helpmode" value="online" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

And it should be using online help again.

Comment: That is what I am not getting. In the Help Library Manager all I have is an option to select a location for the local content. I can browse to a path where local content is placed - that's all -no other option.

Comment: Thanks - it worked. Though when I click on Help Library Manager - I still don't have the options: Choose online or local help, Check for updates online, Install content from online, etc..

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in SSMS 2014.Easier way to do this is:

Help->Manage Help Settings

Chose OK when asked to "Set Local Content Location". 
This will create the folder for local help and will enable the additional setting from where you can choose again local or online help.

Hope this helps!